# What is wrong with this javascript code? It keeps looping without stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, date, countdown

I have this js code. It works but I noticed I get an error like this. "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"
And i notice the errors keeping counting up in firebug. So I assuming it's the for loop that keeps on going. Can you look at the code below and tell me what's wrong with it?

```js
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //Create object with the list of due dates
    //The 'name' will correspond to the field ID to populate the results
    var dueDates = {
        'date1':'2017-04-17 09:55:18',
        'date2':'2017-05-17 09:55:18',
        'date3':'2017-06-17 09:55:18'
    };

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        //Instantiate variables
        var dueDate, distance, days, hours, minutes, seconds, output;
        //Set flag to repeat function
        var repeat = false;
        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        //Iterate through the due dates
        for (var dueDateId in dueDates) {
            //Get the due date for this record
            dueDate = new Date(dueDates[dueDateId]);
            // Find the distance between now an the due date
            distance = dueDate - now;
            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            days    = Math.floor(distance  / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            hours   = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            //Determine the output and populate the corresponding field
            output = "OVERDUE";
            if (distance > 0)
            {
                output = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";
                repeat = true; //If any record is not expired, set flag to repeat
            }
            document.getElementById(dueDateId).innerHTML = output;
            //If flag to repeat is false, clear event
            if(!repeat)
            {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="date1"></div>
<div id="date2"></div>
<div id="date3"></div>
```

Comment: Google `setInterval`.

Comment: "repeat" variable is always true in your code. !repeat always evaluates to false and the clearInterval is never executed

Comment: There is still **2 months and 10 days** untill `2017-06-17 09:55:18` so this will loop each second for 100 days!

Comment: The i noticed what the issue is. If all 3 dates are active, then I don't get the looping error. If even one of the dates is empty, then the looping error begins.  How do I fix that?

Comment: By empty you mean what? The error which you have happens because the `dueDateId` is not a string that equals any id in the dom. Try logging the `dueDateId` before the `getElementById` and see what comes out (or use a debugger).

Comment: By empty, I mean the date is all zeroes like this "0000-00-00 00:00:00". I managed to fix it by doing an if else statement within the js code. Here's the code. https://paste.ofcode.org/bFjCDVbdxKswPBqSSih7vR

Answer (score 1):

Your first due date is future, so the *distance* is positive, and so *repeat* is set to `true` in the very first iteration of the loop. As it never becomes `false` again inside the loop, the `clearInterval` function is not executed in any of the `for` loop iterations. So the `setInterval` callback will be invoked again 1 second later, and the same logic repeats...

Comment: 100 days to be exact :D! `2017-06-17` far far future!

Comment: Yes I am counting down to those 3 different dates.  Before I was testing with my mysql database dates so only 2 dates were active with 3rd one was empty. That's why it was giving me the looping error. But if I have all 3 dates filled, then I no longer get an error.

Comment: I have resolved this by doing and if else statement to hide if the date is empty. https://paste.ofcode.org/bFjCDVbdxKswPBqSSih7vR

Comment: Of course, if you reference an element ID with `getElementById` that is not in your document, you get an error, but the question was also why it just kept going, which is related to `setInterval` and the fact that you never ever execute `clearInterval`.  Also note that in your question you had not provided the data to reproduce the error. The code as you provided it in the question did not have that behaviour since `date1`, `date2`, `date3` all exist in your HTML.